# How to fix an uncaught javascript exception error generated in the internal extendscript code

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I have developed a script for after effects and i was testing it in after effects cc 2019 and everything looks perfect however when i tired to run the script from the ScriptUI folder in after effects cc 2018 i got a random error from the internal adobe code.

Just for records, the script was working fine in after effects cc 2018 but for some reason when AE bugged out and i forced it to quit from the task manager i started getting this error

[Code Error in Extendscript Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nWnj.png)

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thank you guys.

Comment: can you post the script ? I recommend searching in the code for where `abort()` is being called to narrow down the cause of the error being thrown in the first place.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you for the tip but the problem is that this abort function belong to Adobe extendscript internal code not the one i wrote.

Comment: Tricky then: hard to tell without seeing your code, but it feels like you might need to go through a step by step debugging process: follow the flow of your program from the start, at each step double check that all the data coming in is valid and after each API operation the returned result is still valid, where it fails try a break point and watch the variables and the values they hold.

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeProfenza i will try to do so despite it is 3k lines of code!

Comment: I don't envy you buddy :) I've seen worse though (~36K or VB code with ASM code as strings and only 3 functions, autonamed (e.g. _Sub1)). Remember, you've got a debugger and break points, `$.writeln()` will output to ExtendScript Console and if you go from the start you might not need to debug **everything**, just the bit that's not working now. Hope it's an easy one (come constant or whatever changing from one version of AE to another) (speaking of which double check if there are any API changes).

Comment: Thanks mate! i have fixed this issue by rechecking my json file which is the responsible for this error! there was a strange bits of characters like so \ufeff that made the parse to fail (the program coudlnt figure out what type of escaping is that) and i dont know who added that lol so after i deleted that i got everything working fine :)